# Having trouble sending three or more packets consecutively

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient, networkstream

I am trying to implement a Client/Server model using `TCpClient`, with its `Networkstream.Write()/Read()` functions sending/receiving a byte array.

It works most the time, except if I try to send three or more byte arrays in a row right after one another. The client says it sends them all, but the server only receives the first two.

Below is the code I use to write from client to server.

```
byte[] buffer = p.toByteArray(level);

stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
stream.Flush();
```

Is it consolidating them or something?  I just don't understand how the server can receive distinct arrays when I send 2, but not 3 or more.  If I separate the 3 writes, it works OK, but I really don't want to do that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

SOLVED :)
Thanks for all your guys help.  It was pushing 2-3 packets at a time, and my system was thinking 1 burst = 1 packet.  I just rewrote my existing architecture with TCPClient to detect multiple packets :)  Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: This is more likely to be a bug in your *receive* code than the sending code. When in doubt, use Wireshark or equivalen. For more help, please post your server receive code. I suspect you are using a larger buffer than necessary and ignoring data received beyond what you expect.

Comment: Show more code, complete with relevant parts of both the client and the server.

Comment: I concur with Greg's request for using wireshark to look at what's being sent received and your server code.  TCP will definitely try to merge small packets (if you're interested in details, research "Naigle's Algorithm)

Comment: Does it get sent if you close/flush the socket afterward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one very important core rule that is important to account for when you do Sockets programming:

It is not guaranteed that whatever client sent in X writes, server will receive exactly in the same amount of reads. It can be one write on client and 10 reads on server. It can be 10 writes and client and just one read on server.

Let's say the client sends 3 messages, 100 bytes each. Server might receive 150 bytes and then another 150 bytes. Or 100 bytes and 200 bytes.

The only thing that is guaranteed if you work with TCP is that the order will be preserved, in other words that whatever you sent first will arrive first on the server.

You can use one of the following basic techniques to separate the data:

- markers (some kind of byte sequence that delimit messages)
- constant length per message
- length in the message header
- combination of the above

Comment: Is there some setting that I can make it at least do it in whole 'sents' per recieve?  Ie 2 and 1, instead of the 1.5 each you mentioned above?  Why would it always do writes = reads till I get to this threshold?

Comment: @Will - not really. You can set `NoDealy` setting on the socket and also set `SendBufferSize` size close to the size of your message. This will hint not to buffer much on the client before sending. This will alleviate your issue, but will not solve it completely. If you want to make the server robust, you need to make sure server accounts for the rule that I described in my answer.

Comment: @Will - also, if you need to fine-tune the socket, you need to use `Socket` class directly, not the `TcpClient` wrapper.

Comment: @Will As far as I know, any writes == reads should be thought of as an implementation detail. The conceptual "connection" that TCP provides is a continuous stream of bytes, not a collection of distinct packets.