# C# How to send more than one byte streams using TCPClient?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm trying to make **Login feature** by using TCP Client. I have two forms: Client-side and Server-side.

The Client-side handles user input while Server-side connect to database.

The problem is the reader result, which always combine both inputs into one long string like this:

```
   myusernamemypassword
```

Here's part of the **sender** of client-side:

```
    byte[] byteUsername = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(username);
    byte[] bytePassword = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    stream.Write(username, 0, byteUsername.Length);
    stream.Write(password, 0, bytePassword.Length); 
        //if offset != 0, the code always return ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

And the **reader** in server-side:

```
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
```

After long-search I found the solution, **but it can only handle two strings**; the third+ string will be combined together with the second string. I need to send at least 4 strings for other feature.

Here's the **updated reader** code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
int totalRead = 0;
do
{
    int read = client.GetStream().Read(buffer, totalRead, buffer.Length - totalRead);

    totalRead += read;

    list.Add(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, totalRead));

} while (client.GetStream().DataAvailable);
```

I don't quite understand this code. How can it knows which bytes are part of the first string? The `size` of `Read()` parameter is `length-totalRead` which is `length - 0`, it should return the whole buffer right?

Any solution guys?

Thanks before

Comment: See this recent question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949753/tcp-ip-message-framing/11952072#11952072

Comment: "How can it knows which bytes are part of the first string?"  - **It doesn't know** this is one of the reasons you shouldn't use code you don't understand.  What I would do is convert a List<string> into a byte[] and send that instead.  What you could also do is build combine the four strings, and send the length of each string to the server, and decode it that way.  If you want to understand what the code you "found" does, you would need to tell us WHERE you located it, or at the very least provide more information.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325676/having-trouble-sending-three-or-more-packets-consecutively?rq=1

Comment: @Ramhound Do we need to use another TCPClient to send the length of each string?
btw I found it in the e-book my friend gave me. The title is "C# 4.0 How To" by Ben Watson. I can upload it and share the link, but I think I shouldn't spread the piracy further more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prefix each string with its length (in bytes, not characters) as a 4-byte integer.
This way, the server will know how many bytes to read into each string.

Comment: But how to send the length of each string to the server side?

Comment: `BitConverter.GetBytes(byteArray.Length)`

Comment: Thanks, I finally get the logic of this problem.